# The Telegram bot for book information

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, http, telegram

[Telegram Bot that retrieves book information from GoodReads](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145187/telegram-bot-that-retrieves-book-information-from-goodreads/145203?noredirect=1#comment272738_145203)

I've created a Telegram bot that implements the inline/offline modes to get the brief info about a book, searched by title(inline mode) or with command `/random`. The data is retrieved from GoodReads. I was wondering how can I modify the body of 'description', so that I would be able to add here that rating info and name of the author? The "idea" of the interpretation is as an example of IMDB's bot

[image]

## The GoodReads client

```
import goodreads
from goodreads import client
import random

client_key = '[redacted']
client_secret = '[redacted']

gc = client.GoodreadsClient(client_key, client_secret)

def parse_book(book):
    return {
        'title': book_data.title,
        'author': book_data.authors[0],
        'rating': book_data.rating,
        'review': book_data.review,
        'cover': book_data.image_url,
        'link': book_data.link
    }

  def book_info(title):
      books = gc.search_books(str(title), page=1, search_field='all')

      return map(parse_book, books)

  def random_book():
      index = random.randint(1, 1000000)
      book = gc.book(index)

      return parse_book(book)
```

## The Telegram Bot implementation

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import gd

token = '[redacted']
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])  # greeting
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message.chat.id, "Hi! How are you?")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])  # command list
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message.chat.id, "This bot can do: ")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['random']) # /random
def random(message):
    book = random_book()
    text = "Some text"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, disable_web_page_preview=False) 

@bot.inline_handler(lambda query: query.query == 'text')  # inline session
def query_text(query):
    raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
    book_req = book_info(query)
    try:
        result = []
        i = 0
        for book in book_req:
            result.append(types.InlineQueryResultArticle(id=i, 
                title=book[i]['title'],
                url=book[i]['link'],
                hide_url=True,
                description=book[i]['review'],
                thumb_url=book[i]['cover'], thumb_width=48, thumb_height=48
                ))
            i += 1
        bot.answer_inline_query(query.id, result)
    except Exception as e:
        print("{!s}\n{!s}".format(type(e), str(e)))

def main_loop():
    bot.polling(True)
    while 1:
        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main_loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print >> sys.stderr, '\nExiting by user request.\n'
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: this seems to be a follow up to your [previous question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145187/telegram-bot-that-retrieves-book-information-from-goodreads), you should have a link to the previous question. You still put your client secret and key.

Comment: I edited them out, but just as with your previous question, they are still visible in the revision history, so you should **immediately change them** (again?)!!!

Answer (score 1):

`gc` is the name of the [Garbage Collection interface](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/gc.html) module. It shouldn't matter too much, but, when reading your code, it feels like that you are asking the garbage collector to find books and then I remind myself that it isn't actually the garbage collector.

```
index = random.randint(1, 1000000)
```

This was mentioned in the last post. Even if you can't find the specific number you need, you should at least assign `1000000` to some variable something like `MAX_BOOK_NO` so the meaning of such a number is more obvious.

```
    i = 0
    for book in book_req:
    ...
        i += 1
```

This is simplified with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
    for i, book in enumerate(book_req):
    ...
```